# Integration by parts for the conservation of energy of the Schrödinger equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, complex-integration

$u(t,x)$ is a solution of the Schrödinger equation $iu_{t}+\Delta u=0.$

$E(t) := \int |u(t,x)|^2 dx$ is conserved and since $u\bar{u}=|u|^2$ then
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=\int (\bar{u}u_{t}+\bar{u_{t}} u)\, dx.$$ Now using the Schrodinger equation $iu_{t}+\Delta u=0,$ we see that $u_{t}=i\Delta u$. Substituting this into $\frac{d}{dt}E(t)$ we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=\int[\bar{u}(i\Delta u)+\overline{(i\Delta u)}u]\,dx = 2i\operatorname{Im}\int|\nabla u|^{2}dx.$$

I am unsure with how to calculate this integral and give the required result, I know it involves integration by parts but can anyone show me how to actually perform this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a slight mistake in the the signs. Anyway, here is my computation:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}E(t)&=\int (\bar{u}u_{t}+\bar{u_{t}} u)\, dx \\
&=-\int[\bar{u}(i\Delta u)+\overline{(i\Delta u)}u]\,dx  \\
&=-i\int[\bar{u} (\Delta u)-(\Delta\overline{u})u]\,dx
\end{align}

Note the relative minus sign between the two terms. Now you partial integration to transform $\bar{u} (\Delta u)$ into $(\Delta\overline{u})u$, and you see that both halves just cancel.

On second thought, your calculation is fine too. Your last expression is "imaginary part of something real", which is zero.